# Where can I find JS JSON info on raw JSON manipulation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, reference

I can do it via jQuery and/or Underscore JS as arrays of data, but I want to learn the API for just pure RAW JSON. For example, I know there is:

```
delete json.item
```

Which just simply deletes the item, but is there a set place I can go learn the full API?

--UPDATE--

I guess this came out wrong. I want to learn about Douglas Crockfords library, all of it. The JSON.func() library, not just "JSON" which is a string. For example he has a function called `stringify` etc. His site is a total mess, so I was wondering if there was a better place to learn about that JSON library (which has become the standard.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing. Raw JSON is a string, and attempting to manipulate it will only serve to damage it. Always manipulate it after decoding it.

Comment: I mean, JSON by douglas crockford? His library/API has, for example, stringify()? I was wondering where I can find all his functions with documentation. His site is a mess.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` will modify the property of an object, it won't let you manipulate JSON (unless that JSON is stored as the property of an object, in which case it will delete it entirely).

You appear to be asking about how to modify a JavaScript object, in which case, the "API" can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: I mean, JSON by douglas crockford? His library/API has, for example, stringify()? I was wondering where I can find all his functions with documentation. His site is a mess.

Comment: `parse` and `stringify` **are** the full API; it doesn't make sense for a JSON library in JS to do anything else. The documentation at the top of the library file — https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json.js — is clear and comprehensive.